# Questions about Remeshing (Voxel) in the user manual

Tags: retopology, remesh

in the user manual:

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/retopology.html

Under Voxel Size, it mentions that "a value of 0.5m will create topological patches that are about 0.5m". There are two confusions because a voxel is not a line but probably an area (square patch?) or a cube so the unit should be m^2 or m^3? In this case, what is a Voxel and what is a topological patch?

Also, under Voxel Remesh, it states that "Performing this will lose all mesh data layers associated with the original mesh.". What is mean by "mesh data layers"?

Comment: The manual has sometimes errors, is outdated, or incomplete (Todo). I don't know what "topological patches" in this context are. But I guess they mean the length of the edge of a [voxel](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/glossary/index.html#term-Voxel) = *"A cubic 3D equivalent to the square 2D pixel"* (a pixel is the smallest square that a raster image or a monitor can display)

Comment: [mesh data layers](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/modify/data_transfer.html) are Vertex Groups, UV maps, Vertex Colors, Color and GN attributes, Bevel Weights, Seams, Freestyle and Smooth/Sharp edge marks, Crease weights, edited normals, and so on. In other words: the mesh will be destroyed and a new one will be recreated that has a similar shape and volume but a completely different topology and no additional data.

Comment: Is that what some people called "destructive" operation? Is that the reason why some users created a duplicate first before applying the remesh operation in their youtube videos?

Comment: yes, remesh is a destructive operation. It can be only reverted by Undo (Ctrl+Z).